# Cannot get Log aggregation to work on Amazon-Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I tried everything that I could to get the log to aggregate but I couldn't. So I need your help in resolving this issue:

I added this to the yarn-site.xml and restarted but no joy.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
    <description>Where to aggregate logs to.</description>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/logs</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>259200</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds</name>
    <value>3600</value>
</property>
```

When I try to aggregate by:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <ID>
```

This error is being output:

```
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.
```

Comment: You have to add this conf in all the nodes and restart the nodemanager.

Comment: @AmalGJose, that resolved the issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AmalGJose How to restart nodemanager?

Comment: If it is a package based installation you can restart using the command /etc/init.d/hadoop-yarn-nodemanager restart.

Answer (score 0):

Adding above configurations to all nodes as suggested by @AmalGJose resolved the issue.